# Show a file in Android file explorer

Tags: android, file, android-intent

In my Android app the user can add files locally and retrieve files from the server. They are displayed in a list in my app. I want the user to be able to select a file, and display the given file in a file explorer (analagous to "Show in folder" after downloading something in Chrome). Is this possible? I haven't seen a way to do it!
Thanks

P.S. this is what I've tried so far - hacked together from various sources.

```
string path = TSetupBase.Dirs.AttachmentsFolder_ + attachment.FileName;

                Android.Net.Uri selectedUri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(path);
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);

                 intent.SetDataAndType(selectedUri, "resource/folder");
                StartActivity(intent);
```

I get an exception saying it was unable to find an app to handle this intent.

Comment: Can you post your code showing what you've tried so far ?

Answer (score 0):

** **EDIT** **

After your comment that you want the file manager to open with the path on which the file chosen is present then you have to pass the file path as well.. Check the edited code below, line #2

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("file/"+the_path_of_your_file);
    startActivityForResult(intent, YOUR_RESULT_CODE);
```

I'm sure this should work for you.

Comment: But that will just open a file browser in it's initial state. I want the file browser to open with a specific file highlighted.

Comment: @DavidChristopherReynolds sorry i think i misunderstood your question, I will edit it.

Comment: @DavidChristopherReynolds check my updated answer, though it will not highlight the file, it will at least open the file manager with the path of the selected file. Doubt there is a way to show the file highlighted... It depends upon the file manager.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 Intent fileintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        fileintent.setType("gagt/sdf");
        try {
            startActivityForResult(fileintent, PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("tag", "Problems XXXXX ");
        }
```